# svn pre-revprop-change hook message not shown

Tags: svn, hook

With a collegae we placed a hook (the pre-revprop-change hook) in svn. It works correct. If we go to TortoiseSVN -> select a revision wothout a message -> right click and choose 'Edit log message' we get a pop-up window. If one of us enters text and clicks ok it is shown in TortoiseSVN. However, if the other one opens TortoiseSVN the message is not shown. When selecting the revision -> right click and choose 'Edit log message' in the pop-up window the text is shown.

Anyone who knows how to see each others messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will almost certainly be due to TortoiseSVN caching log messages. You can turn this off through the TortoiseSVN settings dialog (right click in a folder, TortoiseSVN menu, Settings) where there is a section for "Log Caching" and a checkbox to enable/disable log caching.

If you turn log caching off, you should see the messages more quickly, but overall TortoiseSVN performance when showing history will be slower.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks. Strange way of caching. If I remove the tick on the checkbox it is shown. When I tick it again the message is empty again. This caching seems to cache things very long and doesn't update (very often).